# count the files and delete the remaining files if the count is greater the given limit

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have used the below script to recursively count the number of files in the directory. In each sub-directory if count is greater than 3, I need to delete the remaining files.

Do I need to add another for loop for each subdirectory and delete the remaining files if it is more than 3?

```
START=$HOME

# change your directory to command line if passed
# otherwise use home directory
[ $# -eq 1 ] && START=$1 || :

if [ ! -d $START ]
then
        echo "$START not a directory!"
        exit 1
fi

# use find command to get all subdirs name in DIRS variable
DIRS=$(find "$START" -type d)

# loop thought each dir to get the number of files in each of subdir
for d in $DIRS
do
   [ "$d" != "." -a "$d" != ".." ] &&  echo "$d dirctory has $(ls -l $d | wc -l) files" || :

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` has already provided the number of sub-directories below `START`. The count is increased by `1` due to inclusion of the `PWD` (`.`). So to get the number of sub-directories below `START` excluding `START` itself:

```
find "$START" -type d | echo "subdirs: $(($(wc -l)-1))"
```

**output example:**

```
subdirs: 6
```

To get the number of files, just use `-type f` instead (no need to subtract 1):

```
find "$START" -type f | echo "files: $(wc -l)"
```

**output example:**

```
files: 128
```

You can put this all together, while limiting the `-maxdepth` of the `find` files to `1` and accomplish what you desire. **Note:** the script below just prints whether it would `keep` or `delete` the files (first 3 in each dir are kept, remaining are deleted). You will need to implement your own scheme of which to keep/delete to meet your needs. This will give you an idea of what you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

start="${1:-$PWD}"

[ -d "$start" ] || {
    printf "error: directory not accessible '%s'\n", "$start"
    exit 1;
}

declare -a files                                # declare an array to hold files

for i in $(find "$start" -type d); do           # find all subdirs

    [ "$i" = "$PWD" ] && continue               # skip the current (top) dir

    printf "\nprocessing: %s\n\n" "$i"          # simple dir info output (not needed)

    files=( $(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f) )  # fill array w/files in each dir (no subs)
    if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then           # if subdir has files
        echo "num files: ${#files[@]}"          # No. of files in dir info (not needed)
        for ((j=0; j<${#files[@]}; j++)); do    # for each file
            if [ "$j" -lt 3 ]; then             # if first 3, keep
                printf "  keeping : %s\n" "${files[j]}"
            else                                # files 4+ delete
                printf "  deleting: %s\n" "${files[j]}"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

**sample output:**

```
$ bash del3dirs.sh

processing: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/sav

num files: 5
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/sav/dna.sh
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/sav/dict-sort_1.sh
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/sav/_20140702-211202.tar.xz
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/sav/dict-sort.sh
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/sav/dict-sort_2.sh

processing: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp

num files: 13
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/File1950text.doc
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/vcs1dump
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/File2014text.xls
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/File307list.cvs
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/vcsa1dump
  (snip)

processing: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/a

num files: 2
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/a/b/b.txt
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/tmp/a/b/b.txt.bac

processing: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat

num files: 68
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/outlier.dat
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/3line.dat.sav
  keeping : /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/f1f2.dat
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/datb.dat
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/lline.dat
  deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/vowels.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my intention is to count the number of files in each sub-directory and delete the remaining files if the count exceeds "3". Is that possible?

Comment: OK, give me a second and I'll amend the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am check it :)

Comment: It works great thanks!! except one condition if the name is like this "test(copy).txt". then it is taking as two files.

Comment: You will have to elaborate (post example). No expansion or word splitting should take place on `"test(copy).txt"`. I'll test. Oh, those don't look like normal file name characters. Bash complains creating a filename with parens unless they are escaped. Let me see if there is a quick fix. What `OS` are you on? Just tested, and it worked fine here: `deleting: /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/tmp/b/text(copy).txt`